# Shell script to pull text from webpage and trim

Tags: linux, shell, html, pull

I don't know how to trim text honestly.

What I have so far:

```
wget --output-document=- http://www.geupdate.com 2>/dev/null \
| grep last \
```

Outputs:

```
<li><b><img src='http://www.geupdate.com/img/arrow-tail.png' align='left'>Time since last update</b>: <br />0 day, 19 hours, 23 min, 36 sec</li><li><b><img src='http://www.geupdate.com/img/ledlightblue.png' align='left'>An Update to occur within:</b> (<a href='http://www.geupdate.com/update-prediction/'><font size='-2'>?</font></a>) <br />0 day, 21 hours, 56 min, 30 sec</li>               </ul>
```

What I actually want to trim out of this is:

```
0 day, 19 hours, 23 min, 36 sec
```

If anyone can tell me how write something or write it if it's that simple, that would be nice!

When I run this:

```
wget --output-document=- http://www.geupdate.com 2>/dev/null \
| grep last \
| grep -o '[[:digit:]]* day.* sec'
```

I get this:

```
0 day, 19 hours, 43 min, 16 sec</li><li><b><img src='http://www.geupdate.com/img/ledlightblue.png' align='left'>An Update to occur within:</b> (<a href='http://www.geupdate.com/update-prediction/'><font size='-2'>?</font></a>) <br />0 day, 21 hours, 36 min, 50 sec
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wget --output-document=- http://www.geupdate.com 2>/dev/null \
| grep last \
| grep -o '[[:digit:]]* days*, [[:digit:]]* hours*, [[:digit:]]* min, [[:digit:]]* sec' \
| head -1
```

Comment: How would I cut off everything after the "sec" then?

Comment: @Aaron: That *does* cut off everything after the `sec`. The `-o` flag to `grep` tells it to produce only the substring that matches the pattern, rather than pulling the entire line containing it. ("O" for "only". Though the mnemonic explains only half of its behavior: `echo 1234 | grep -o '[1234]'` will print each of `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` on separate lines, which IMHO isn't obvious from the name "only".)

Comment: I updated my original post to show what I get when I run what you suggested!

Comment: @Aaron: Oops, sorry, I didn't notice that there were two separate instances of the "# day, # hours, # min, # sec" formula. I've modified my answer to give a stricter match that will catch only one instance at a time, and added a `| head -1` to suppress all but the first instance.

Comment: That's awesome. How do you people know this stuff :3. So if I wanted to catch the second instance of the days hours and min. What would you add to skip the first one and get the second?

Comment: Re: how to know this stuff: I don't know. I've slowly come across these utilities over time. I don't know of a good resource that walks you through all the useful ones. I suppose http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unix_utilities is a good start. Re: to catch the nth instance: instead of `| head -1`, you can do (for example) `| head -5 | tail -1` to get the fifth instance. `head -5` outputs the first five lines of its input, and `tail -1` outputs the last line of *its* input, so `head -5 | tail -1` outputs the fifth line of its input.

Comment: So head -5 will show 5 instances and head -5 | tail -1 will show the last one only, or that's how it does when I do it. Thanks.